# Been hired at senior level, but other people of my experience and skill are Staff Level?

Tags: tech-industry, payscale

So I've been hired by a big tech company (not faang tho). During the interview process the recruiter proposed me a Senior level, hurriedly mentioning that there was also staff and higher level, but they were just a few of them.

After joining I noticed that most seniors have half my years of experience and sometimes Staff even less. When working with Staff level engineers I noticed some of them also have less skills than me (sometimes coming out with gross mistakes or lack of knowledge). Also Staff is not the highest (as suggested), but there's Senior Staff, Principal...

I'm very annoyed because I had not been proposed Staff level at all. I feel a little bit cheated on, like they hired me at a lower pay grade, just to pay me less. This is really bothering me, for financial reasons, but above all for professionnal reasons, why don't I get what I deserve? I am not sure what would be the best way to address this.

This is a job in Tech, where you have the so called Technical career path. Above mentioned levels do not involve any management. It's just tech skills.

Comment: _"why don't I get what I deserve?"_ That's something you should have stated in the interview-process - you ask for what you perceive as an acceptable paycheck - don't look at other peoples salaries..

Comment: The thing that annoys me is that he made it look like the level above was so much above my skills set, to make it look unattainable. While it was not. That's what I feel wrong. How could I had known more about internal structure before joining?

Comment: Were you hired at the position that you applied for and at the payrate that was acceptable to you?

Comment: I did not apply I was cantacted by the recruiter. The payrate is acceptable yes, but as I explained, it is not a pay issue to me.

Comment: Was it an external recruiter who worked for his money?

Answer (score 8):

> why don't I get what I deserve

Presumably you accepted an offer for this job at a certain rate of pay that you were satisfied with.  It's not clear what has changed other than your attitude.  Now you think you "deserve" more because there are others who, in your view, get paid more and don't know what you know.

If that's the case, then I believe you are the problem.  Quit now and find a job with a "title" that suits you.

On the other hand, it's not at all uncommon to find yourself in a lower job classification when moving to a new position.  If you're good you will quickly find yourself in line for promotions and merit increases.  Distinguish yourself as a top performer regardless of job title and you will get noticed.  Prepare for your next performance review with specific and measurable reasons why your performance is beyond that which your current title calls for.  People get promoted because they consistently perform at a level above their current job title and pay rate.

Answer (score 1):

> why don't I get what I deserve?

Maybe you are?

Titles are not always about experience. There are other attributes that can factor into how titles and pay-grades are governed. Maybe those employees have been working in the org longer? Maybe they have undertaken specific training? Or gotten large projects over the line? Or have specific educational qualifications? Or shown some aptitude at leading? Or mentoring? Or anything else that your employer deems reasonable.

Some of these things may be in your grasp in the short term, so you should ask your employer what they are, if they matter to you.

Comment: Those are new hires just like me. That's the annoying part. If they were internal people I would factor in the internal experience and it would surely make sense. But they are not. If the interview process is different (and more challenging) I would have been happy to undertake it. But I think I understand that it was just the same

Answer (score 0):

> During the interview process the recruiter proposed me a Senior level, hurriedly mentioning that there was also staff and higher level, but they were just a few of them.

I'm not sure on the levels but I assume Senior < Staff < other levels. So at that company everyone starting off gets a Senior title?

It sounds to me like you're assuming title = higher pay grade. So your assumption is that someone above Senior *must* be getting paid more. But that isn't necessarily true at all. In most companies, especially tech companies, people get pay raises only when they change jobs. If they stayed at their current job they only made 2-3% increases per year. So your assumptions are wrong and inaccurate.

> I feel a little bit cheated on, like they hired me at a lower pay grade, just to pay me less.

That's salary negotiation 101. The recruiter probably could have paid you more but since you asked for it, you got what you wanted. Now you're regretting your decision on it and that's really on you, not them.

However, it is always dangerous to assume others are getting paid more. It is also dangerous to go around asking if people get paid more. I mean they may be lying to you because people don't normally talk about those things at work places.